# Is there any command to find mean of first 5 values then next 5 values for a total of 1000 values in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mean, calculated-columns

Is there any command to find mean of first 5 values then next 5 values from a total of 25 values present in a vector in MATLAB. If the dataset is X.
If anyone can help me to provide a code where I can get mean at every 5th value.

```
X=[4 5 6 7 2 5 7 4 2 6 7 3 2 1 5 7 8 3 4 6 8 4 2 6 8];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are plenty of different ways to accomplish this task. If you could give us a sample of your attempt we might be able to better judge your understanding level and provide a response that works for you.

Comment: Hi. Can you please guide me with the most easiest way to solve the problem. I have tried various codes but the answer from those are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple way to do it. Rearrange the vector into a matrix loop over the columns and take the mean of all values in each column. Store the results in a new vector.

```matlab
X=[4 5 6 7 2 5 7 4 2 6 7 3 2 1 5 7 8 3 4 6 8 4 2 6 8];
Xr = reshape(X,5,5)
cols = size(Xr)(2)
avgs=zeros(1,cols)

for i= 1:cols
    avgs(i) = mean(Xr(:,i))
end
```

Comment: Reviewing the matlab documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html, you can see that we could simplify the code and remove the for loop and simply say avgs = mean(Xr,1). Similar to the response provided by Ratbert.

Comment: If you are going to loop, at least [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) the output array.

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance reshape the vector in an array with `reshape` and then apply the `mean` function:

```
M = mean(reshape(X, [5, numel(X)/5]),1);
```

or simply

```
M = mean(reshape(X, 5, []),1);
```

But there as stated in the comments there are many other ways.

Comment: You can use an empty array in `reshape` to have it compute the size of one output dimension: `reshape(X,5,[])`.